# How to resolve this Gradle Build issue?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin

I am creating an Android App and I need drag and move feature. So, for that, I found a library named "Advanced RecyclerView".

So I tried to add the above library using Gradle for Android.

The lines are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

**My Issue**

After adding these lines I got following error on Gradle Build:

> Error:Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0. 
>   Required by:
>       Nuvo_Rider:app:unspecified 
>       Nuvo_Rider:app:unspecified > com.l4digital.fastscroll:fastscroll:1.0.4
>       Nuvo_Rider:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:25.3.1
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

**My steps to resolve**
I tried changing `compileSDKversion` to 27 and also added recyclerview.V27.0.2, but couldn't find a solution.

**My Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'
def AndroidSupportVersion = '25.3.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'
    }
}

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 25
//    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nuvo.rider"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        //versionCode 6
        //versionName "1.2.3"
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        // vector appCompact
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

apt {
    arguments {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //Default
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    // compile "com.android.support:design:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Card View
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Recyleerview
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Annotation
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    //Stripe
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //Fabric
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Scan Card
    //Multidex
    //Validator
    //EditText
    //Facebook SDK
    //Firebase & GeoFire
    //glide

    //Route Drawer
    //Top Snackbar
    //Universal Image Loader

    //Stripe
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //Fabric
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Volley

    compile('com.l4digital.fastscroll:fastscroll:1.0.4') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1') {
        transitive = true;
        //    exclude group: 'universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar';
    }

    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

**Final Words**

Since I am new to Android, I can't fix this issue.

Comment: In this case its always a good Idea to use the sample app provided by the library, and build your app on top of that. fixing version issues are really frustrating. Later if you want you can update your versions along.

Comment: @Muhammad .. Yes. A Good Idea. But since my App is huge , it is difficult to integrate an other app.. !!

Answer (score 1):

**FOLLOW THE STEPS**

Add the following lines of code into your [build.gradle](https://gradle.org/).

**Step 1:**

```
dependencies {
   implementation ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This library is served on [jCenter](https://bintray.com/h6ah4i/maven/android-advancedrecyclerview/). If the above gradle setting not getting work, try adding the following lines.

**Step 2:**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

> **ATTENTION:**  Make sure you Global Gradle Setting wasn't *offline*
>
> Check it,
>
> **File > Setting > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle**

If `offline work` checkbox is checked, then please uncheck it.

[image]
Try to `Clean` and `Rebuild` project.

Comment: No Solution .. Same problem arising again

Comment: Make sure your jCenter() defined in project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

use same versions check below

```
       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'
def AndroidSupportVersion = '24.2.1' //change here

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'
    }
}

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 25
//    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nuvo.rider"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        //versionCode 6
        //versionName "1.2.3"
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        // vector appCompact
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

apt {
    arguments {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //Default
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    // compile "com.android.support:design:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Card View
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Recyleerview
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion"
    //Annotation
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    //Stripe
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //Fabric
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Scan Card
    //Multidex
    //Validator
    //EditText
    //Facebook SDK
    //Firebase & GeoFire
    //glide

    //Route Drawer
    //Top Snackbar
    //Universal Image Loader

    //Stripe
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //Fabric
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Volley

    compile('com.l4digital.fastscroll:fastscroll:1.0.4') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1') {
        transitive = true;
        //    exclude group: 'universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar';
    }

    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1' //change here
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Comment: No solution. Same problem with same above mentioned error message!!!!! @Omi